# Choosing the initial simplex in the Nelder-Mead optimization algorithm

Tags: mathematical-optimization, simplex

What's the best way to initialize a simplex for use in a Nelder-Mead simplex search from a user's 'guess' vertex?

Comment: More info here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11590-022-01953-y

Comment: I just looked at that link again today and it looks like they have _withdrawn_ open access on the paper - it is now priced at $29.95!  Can you or anyone confirm this from another location? Update, it has now reappeared as a download - weird!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a *best* way to choose the initial simplex in the Nelder-Mead method, but the following is what is done in common practice.

The construction of the initial simplex `S` is obtained from generating `n+1` vertices `x0,..,xn` around what you call a user's "guess" vertex `xin` in a `N` dimensional space. The most frequent choice is

```
x0=xin
```

and the remaining `n` vertices are then generated so that

```
xj=x0+hj*ej
```

where `ej` is the unit vector of the `j`-th coordinate axis in `R^n` and `hj` is a step-size in the direction of `ej`.

```
hj = 0.05    if (x0)j is non-zero
hj = 0.00025 if (x0)j=0
```

with (x0)j the j-th component of x0. Note that this is the choice in Matlab's *fminsearch* routine, which is based on the Nelder-Mead scheme.

You can find some more information in

[F. Gao, L. Han, "Implementing the Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm with adaptive parameters", *Comput. Optim. Appl.*, DOI 10.1007/s10589-010-9329-3](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~fuchang/res/ANMS.pdf)

Comment: Just for info, the link that @craigB gave above is recent, and open-access.  It describes an algorithm for building a regular simplex _around_ the starting point.  Recommended reading as it is not overly mathematical and gives clear observations and recommendations.

Comment: Just to add: I believe the method above is used in things like Matlab and scipy.  It is a very arbitrary and lazy approach, and the vertyex "offset" values involve some pretty big assumptions about the "scale" of the problem!

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no general rule to determine best the initial simplex of the Nelder-Mead optimization because this required at least a vague knowledge of the response surface.

However, it can be a reasonable policy to set the points in such a way that the simplex covers virtually the entire possible range. The algorithm of Nelder-Mead will shrink automatically 
the simplex and aproximate to the optimum. The practical advantage of this policy is that you 
will obtain a better overall-knowledge of the response-function.

We have done some tests with HillStormer(["http://www.berkutec.com"](http://www.berkutec.com)). This program permits to test these policies on testfunctons and we found that this plicy works rather well.

Please remember that the first simplex-opereation is añways a reflection. If the starting simplex covers the whole permitted range the reflection necessarily will give a point off limits. But HillStormer allows to use linear constraints and can avoid this problem.

You can find some more information in the system-help of HillStormer.

B. Kühne

Comment: the page does not exist anymore

Comment: Not true, it only does a reflection if the trial point is better than the second worst point.  Try it with a sphere function so that the simplex is centered on the origin.  It does a "contract in" step!